# What does "Infertile, Offspring Viable," mean? How does that work?

Tags: terminology, biology, mistranslation

Yesterday I saw the sentence **"Infertile, Offspring Viable"**

What does that even mean?

If the parents are infertile, then they can't have produced children in the first place.
Does this have a different meaning in English?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Could you expand the quote and give us the source?

Comment: Answering really needs more context.  However, "infertile" could refer to the offspring.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because more context is needed.

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/392678/91730) on another question, which suggests that in the medical world fertility is to do with having children, whereas fecundity is to do with the *ability* to have children. Seems the wrong way around to me, but it *might* explain the phrase you have found.

Comment: @AndyT Actually, that answer references a restricted usage in demographics, specifically _fertility rate_. In medical dictionaries,  "fertility" is [_the capacity to conceive or to induce conception._](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/fertility), which may be why that whole question may have seemed off to you, as it did to me.

Answer (score 1):

No, your phrase (it is not a sentence, which may have caused some of the problem) means what you think it does. What is intended by 'the offspring of an infertile organism' is something that only reading the scientific paper would reveal. It might be, for example, that the 'mother' is unable to give birth, but viable offspring can result from a test-tube conception; whatever is meant, it is a scientific and not a linguistic problem.